# config_id under core_config_data - important?

Tags: magento-1.7, configuration

I have my production and development sites. They have had different history of installing/uninstalling extensions therefore under `core_config_data` the `config_id` does not match unfortunately.

I am wanting to copy over a bunch of settings from the dev site to production however it seems like I'll be skipping a 50 or so ID numbers when I export and import. Does this matter? I am thinking it should be fine as long as there are no overlaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be fine. Config values are always triggered by `path`.

If I'm not mistaken `config_id` is only there for a primary key.

Answer (score 2):

The `config_id` is not important unless you have some custom code that uses it. (I hope you don't).

The important columns in the `core_config_data` table are `path` (most important), `scope`, `scope_id`.

Comment: For once in my live I was quicker then you.

Comment: @Tim. yeah...I'm starting to lose it. I'm getting old but so is everybody else and I guess it's not a good excuse.

Comment: you would not believe me but I recently discovered that I'm getting old also.